# make unsubscribe from javascript event in C# code

Tags: c#, javascript, events, unsubscribe

i have got such a problem here:

i have a webpage in webbrowser control. that page uses javascript and had subscribed to number of events (i.e. click).

here is algorithm that needed:

1. load page in webbrowser component
2. in C# part of code force page to unsubscribe from javascript event

is there anyway to do that?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. method:** create the unsubscription functions in javascript and then call it from c# side,

in the page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // assign the event to the element
   document.getElementById("myElem").onclick = function(){
       //your code here
   }

   // clear the event
   function clearEvent(){
       document.getElementById("myElem").onclick = function(){
          return false;
       }
   }
</script>
```

in C# side:

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)IE.Document;
IHTMLWindow2 parentWindow = doc.parentWindow;
if (parentWindow != null)
    parentWindow.execScript("clearEvent();", "javascript");
}
```

**2. method:** call the unsubscription code directly from c#

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)IE.Document;
IHTMLWindow2 parentWindow = doc.parentWindow;
if (parentWindow != null)
    parentWindow.execScript("document.getElementById('myElem').onclick=function(){return false;}", "javascript");
}
```

Comment: i have got an exception "Specified cast is not valid" on following string:                                                      IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2) webbrowser.Document.DomDocument;

Comment: try `IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2) webbrowser.Document;`

Comment: that gives `Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' to 'mshtml.IHTMLDocument2'`

Comment: i've got .NET 3.5 Client Profile, if that info changes anything.

Comment: Ok, change the `IHTMLDocument2` to `HTMLDocument`, and `IHTMLWindow2` to `HTMLWindow`, and `doc.parentWindow` to `doc.Window` or `doc.parentWindow` or `doc.Window.parentWindow` etc.

Comment: that was my bad: webbrowser component was in different thread, just needed to use Invoke instead of direct code. sorry (* in any case, can i unload window.onbeforeunload event that way?

Comment: that worked! window.onbeforeunload = null instead of function(){return false}. thanks very much!